# code works fine on emulator but getting nil on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, native

this code is working fine and i get button while i test this code on emulator but I get nil when I test the on real device.
button is declared in header file interface

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)    UIButton *button;
```

then it is synthesized in implementation file

```
@synthesize button;
```

then in a function call i am doing this

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

screenHeight = screenHeight - 135;

//Call
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

when i run this code on real device (iphone 5) the button is always nil. I have noticed while debugging that after running last line
the execution goes back to

```
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

and starts again, by the way there is no loop code here.. I cant understand this phenomena. what am i missing here.

Comment: What calls the method from where is your code?

Comment: there doesn't appear to be enough code here to see what is happening. how is button declared, are you using a storyboard or creating it programatically?

Comment: i am not using storyboard, after creating I am adding it as a subview programatically.

Comment: Change your property to have a strong reference, it's getting deallocated before you add it as a subview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a weak reference to your button, so it's getting deallocated before you add it as a subview. You can either change it to have a strong reference:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;
```

Or keep a reference to the button while you add it to your view:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
_button = myButton;
```

It is now retained by the view so won't get released.

Answer (score 1):

code1 :

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

screenHeight = screenHeight - 135;
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

code2:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
CGFloat a = rect.size.width;
CGFloat b = rect.size.height;

b = b - 1;
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

I run code1 and code2 in the device,I find that

code1 will go back to `CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;`

and code2 will not go back after running last line.

I guess maybe something relation about the device efficiency or the function(`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`) .

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks you caught the execution thing but this didn't solve the issue.